# Exception: type 'Future<User>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I posted this question a while back and i some really good answers, But I am now getting this error
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'receiverId=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: receiverId="null-Rxe7459XVwM4chzI6AP5XkixTql1"

```
 readLocal() async {
 FirebaseUser user =  await _authMethods.getCurrentUser();
senderId = user.uid ?? ''; 
if ( senderId.hashCode <=  receiverId.hashCode) {
  message.senderId = '$senderId-$receiverId';
} else {
  message.receiverId = '$receiverId-$senderId';
}

Firestore.instance.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(senderId).updateData({'chattingWith': receiverId});

  setState(() {});
  }
```

here is my future

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
FirebaseUser currentUser;
currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
return currentUser;

 }
```

Please help me out I'm really new to flutter and trying to finish my first application.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be more than one error here.

You're trying to attribute the Future function to the senderId variable, but a Future is asynchronous, so you want to await for the value.

But this alone may cause yet another error, because getCurrentUser will return a FirebaseUser, and you want the user ID string. So you probably need this:

```
FirebaseUser user = await _authMethods.getCurrentUser();
senderId = user.uid ?? '';
```

Comment: hello George thank you for your answer but i'm getting an error with 'uid' The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'Future<FirebaseUser>'. please help me again

Comment: @AliMuloway I have edited the code, see if it works now. I have also found that it might be a problem with the version of Firebase you're using. they have changed some method names in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

You same issues in the code let fix theme one by one:

1. `getCurrentUser` is `async` function so you have to `await _authMethods.getCurrentUser()`
2. `getCurrentUser` will return `FirebaseUser` which means this is an `object` but by writing `_authMethods.getCurrentUser() ?? ''` you said if the result of `_authMethods.getCurrentUser()` is not null then assign this value to `senderId` else assign `''` which is a `String`, so `String` cannot be assigned to `senderId`, You can assign `null` instead.